Flutter App does not return back after Apple OAuth in Android
I am developing a Flutter app that is Supabase-backed and not self-hosting. All native and web sign-ins and Google sign-ins for Apple are working. However, apple sign-in for Android does not work. I can reach the login page but can't return to the app even though I built deep linking. After the confirmation with Apple ID, I realized that Supabase always tries to connect the default site URL instead of redirected URLs. If I put a website to the site URL (e.g. http://localhost:3000), I can see the success code (https://localhost:3000/?code=XXXXXXXXXX), and the review doesn't go back to the app in the emulator. But if I put my deep-linking info in the site URL (e.g. com.example.supabaselogin), apple gives the error in the attachment.
Apple Error
Supabase Config
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    if (!kIsWeb && Platform.isIOS) {
    return signInWithApple(); //this native part works
  } else if (!kIsWeb && Platform.isAndroid) {
    await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(OAuthProvider.apple,
    redirectTo: "com.example.mobileAppTemplate://login-callback/"); 
    //this part doesnt work
  }
    await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(OAuthProvider.apple, redirectTo: redirectTo); //this web part works
  },
  child: const Text('Sign in with Apple')),

AndroidManifest:
<intent-filter>                 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />                 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />                  
    <data                     
         android:scheme="com.example.mobileAppTemplate"                     
         android:host="login-callback" /> 
</intent-filter>

I have successfully implemented other signs in and tried the supasocialsauth library with a different scheme and host, but the same.
I have also tried manual deep linking using the app_links library. It works on the terminal but not for Apple sign-in; I can't return my app using a URL or other ways.
Updated: I guess everything is correct, but if I want to use app return deep linking (e.g. com.example.mobileAppTemplate://login-callback), Apple gives an error and can't return to the app. If I want to use URL-based deep linking (e.g. http://localhost/foo), Apple returns a redirect to the URL. I have not solved the problem yet.

Can you try with all lower-case deep link?
